# PCI nodes in Device Tree

Tags: embedded-linux, pci, dts, pci-e

Is it necessary that the nodes shown in "lspci" output, have to be defined in device tree ? I have device tree file for P2041RDB. In that only one node is created for pci i.e. bus 0. Now I have customized the reference board and connected one pcie-pci bridge to bus 0 annd four pci devices are connected to that bridge. So in my lspci output, six node is showing. So is it necessary that I have to declare it all in device tree.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, peripherals connected to the PCI-bus doesn't need to be in the DTS file, as they can be enumerated during runtime.

Peripherals sitting on non-enumerable buses, OTOH, needs to be added to the DTS file. This could be peripherals on the memory bus, I2C, SPI, etc.

Comment: ok thank you @Anders. one more querry, should I declare that extrernal pcie-pci bridge in dts? because out of four pci device, interrupt test is failing for one pci device.

Comment: If the bridge is connected through a PCI-bus, you shouldn't need to add it to the DTS file.

Comment: Thank you for your response @anders. Yes bridge is connected through bus. So if we not declare it in dts then how interrrupt mapping is done ?